# How to handle right button clicks in QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing something similar to Eclipse's Package Explorer, using `QTreeWidget`, but I don't know how to handle right mouse button clicks.

How do I use Qt creator so I can handle right clicks on a `QTreeWidgetItem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the context menu policy on the tree view item and then create a signal/slot event handlers as per usual.

For an example you can refer to this:

```
ui->treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

connect(ui->treeView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)),
        this, SLOT(onCustomContextMenu(const QPoint &)));
```

Then just implement the onContextMenu function above